# Is Goto the right command to perform a function?

Tags: autohotkey

Let I have a function like the one in the [**AutoHotkey documentation**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Goto.htm):

```
Goto, MyLabel
...
MyLabel:
Sleep, 100
...
```

In fact, I do not need to jump to `MyLabel`, I just need to run `MyLabel` following the straight flow of command lines in my code.

Actually, what I am looking for is just a command like "Do `MyLabel`!" or "Execute `MyLabel`!" or "Run `MyLabel`!" as well.

Is actually `Goto` the only way offered by AutoHotkey to do such a thing although one doesn't need to jump any command line at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter Goto, the behaviour is like this:

The next line executed will be the one line after the label and the
code continues to run from that location.

While Goto is OK for quick and dirty programming, it is highly recommended to avoid it like the plague because I makes it really difficult to understand how code behaves if you have a few Gotos in it.

If you need to execute lines out of order, writing a function is a cleaner way to do it.

The "Do" Mylabel as more like the Gosub command you asked you in a different question.

An even better solution is your own function.

```
; do some stuff here
MyFunction()
; do some more stuff here
return

MyFunction()
{
  ; do stuff in here
  return
}
```

Comment: Does `MyFunction` would work also if it was empty of arguments between brackets? Something like `MyFunction(){Click 44, 85}` would actually click on 44, 85 coordinates?

Comment: If you had `MyFunction(){Click 44, 85} ` at the end of your code and called `MyFunction() ` in the main program, yes, it would click.

Comment: BTW, Autohotkey comes with a great help file which also has a chapter on functions with many examples. It online [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm)